# Read string as variable RUBY

Tags: ruby, csv

I am pulling the following string from a CSV file, from cell A1, and storing it as a variable:

```
#{collector_id}
```

So, cell A1 reads `#{collector_id}`, and my code essentially does this:

```
test = #excel_cell_A1
```

However, if I then do this:

```
puts test
```

I get this:

```
#{collector_id}
```

I need `#{collector_id}` to read as the actual variable `collector_id`, not the code that I am using to call the variable. Is that possible?

Thanks for the help. I am using ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. We need to see actual code that will at least be accepted by the Ruby interpreter. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` or `gsub` to replace expected input values:

```
collector_id = "foo"
test = '#{collector_id}'
test.sub("\#{collector_id}", "#{collector_id}") #=> "foo"
```

I would avoid the use of `eval` (or at least sanity check what you are running) to reduce the risk of running arbitrary code you receive from the CSV file.

Comment: good advice. I think this will suffice, and I can avoid using `eval` as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test_to_s = eval("\"#{ test }\"")
puts test_to_s
```

`%q["#{ test }"]` will build the string `"#{collector_id}"` (the double quotes are part of the string, `"#{collector_id}".length == 17`) which then will be evaluated as ruby code by `eval`

Comment: NEVER EVER use `eval` on user supplied data. You have just created a nice remote code execution vulnerability (which is among the worst kind of security issues).

Comment: I agree with the security issue- Fortunately, for my particular case, my team will be creating the csv file I am pulling from. It is basically a content file for emails.